# Independently consuming websocket messages (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

Is there a way to consume messages twice from a websocket connection using two separate `async for` loops?

Running the code below gives **RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message**.

```
import websockets
import asyncio

async def foo(ws):
    async for msg in ws:
        print(f"foo: {msg}")


async def bar(ws):
    async for msg in ws:
        print(f"bar: {msg}")


async def main():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://echo.websocket.org") as ws:
        asyncio.create_task(foo(ws))
        asyncio.create_task(bar(ws))
        await ws.send("Hello")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Do you want to read the *same message* twice, or do you want to read *two messages* at once?

Comment: Read the same message twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a broadcast function that reads through `ws` once, and transmits each message into multiple generators. For example (untested):

```
def broadcast(stream, num):
    # iterate over the stream just once, but put each message into
    # multiple queues
    queues = []
    async def consume():
        async for msg in stream:
            for queue in queues:
                await queue.put(msg)
        for queue in queues:
            await queue.put(None)
    asyncio.create_task(consume())

    # create the queues and return the generators that transmit
    # their contents
    async def transmit(queue):
        while True:
            msg = await queue.get()
            if msg is None:
                break
            yield msg

    iters = []
    for _ in range(num):
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
        iters.append(transmit(queue))
        queues.append(queue)

    return iters
```

With that in place, you `main()` could look like this:

```
async def main():
    async with websockets.connect("wss://echo.websocket.org") as ws:
        foo_stream, bar_stream = broadcast(ws, 2)
        asyncio.create_task(foo(foo_stream))
        asyncio.create_task(bar(bar_stream))
        await ws.send("Hello")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!

Comment: Just one question though. If, in `foo` I break out of the for loop, will messages still be broadcast to `foo_stream`? Will this clog up memory if I'm creating lots of streams, and often breaking out of them?

Comment: @Jack Well spotted. This design expects all the returned generators to be drained and will otherwise accumulate messages in the queue without bounds. (I expected the network to be the bottle-neck.) You can replace `asyncio.Queue()` with `asyncio.Queue(1)` which will provide back-pressure in case you pause draining some of them, but at the expense of pausing other generators. If you want the ability to permanently break out of a generator, you will need to add some more communication code. That is a good exercise, and (if you get stuck) possible material for a separate question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If it's not too much to ask, may you be able to point me in the right direction with regards to the extra "communication code" that I'd have to write? Does it involve with statements?

Comment: @Jack `with` could be used to make it more convenient, but the important bit is to implement the functionality. You need the ability to remove a queue from the list of queues. E.g. you can create a new function along with `transmit` and attach it as an attribute of your choice (e.g. `cancel`) of each generator in `iters`. This will allow the caller to call something like `stream.cancel()`  after breaking off `async for msg in stream`. (And yes, you can automate by providing a context manager and mandating the use of `with`, but you need to have the functionality in place first.)